# How to convert all text into 1 except "0"s and first two fields in a csv file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line, bioinformatics

I have several large.csv files that I'd like to convert to binary (1 and 0) format. In which all cells containing text would become 1 and 0 would remain 0, except first two fields.

```
head Test.csv
Iss1,1,0,0,Hsapiens-I34,0,0,0,Mmusculus-H01,0,0
Iss1,11,0,Scerevisiae-U09,Hsapiens-I05,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,Hsapiens-I05,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I31,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,Mmusculus-H13,0,0,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I31
Iss1,41,0,Scerevisiae-U09,0,0,0,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I21
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,Scerevisiae-U25,0,Hsapiens-I21
Iss1,61,0,0,Hsapiens-I34,0,0,0,Mmusculus-H13,0,0
```

The expected outcome would be

```
head Test.csv
Iss1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Iss1,61,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

Where all text in the file is converted into 1.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me some suggestions on how to overcome this.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `awk` you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {$i==0?1:$i=1}} 1' test.csv
```

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}` - set in- and output separator to comma
- `for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)` - we'll loop over fields 3 until max field number `NF`
- `$i==0?1:$i=1` - if field `i` is `0`, do nothing (`1`) else set field `i` to `1`
- `1` - `awk` interprets one as true and defaults to printing the record

---

As suggested in the comments by @EdMorton using `$1=($i!=0)` is a shorter alternative to `$i==0?1:$i=1`

- `$i!=0` is a logical test if field `i` is **not** `0`. `awk` will return `1` for `true` and `0` for `false` and overwrite the field value accordingly

Answer (score 5):

using perl:

```
$ perl -F, -lne 'my @out = map { /^0$/ ? 0 : 1 } splice @F,2;
                 unshift @out, @F;
                 print join(",",@out)' Test.csv 
Iss1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Iss1,61,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Zed227,28897871,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Zed227,28897881,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Zed227,28897891,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Zed227,28897901,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
lad1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
lad1,11,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
lad1,21,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

How it works:

Perl command-line options:

- The `-F,` option tells perl to use a comma as the field delimiter.  `-F` also triggers auto-splitting of each input line, with the fields going into an array called `@F` - this is similar to how awk auto-splits fields into $1, $2, $3, etc.
- `-l` tells perl to automatically handle line-endings, e.g. removing newlines from the input and adding them back to output from `print`.
- `-n` makes perl run similarly to `sed -n` - i.e. read and process each line, but only print what it is explicitly told to.
- `-e` tells perl that the next argument is the script to run.

The script:

- perl's `splice()` removes a portion of an array, and returns that portion to the caller....so `splice @F,2` removes and returns all but the first two elements of the `@F` array.  Actually, `splice` can do a lot more than that, but that's all I'm using it for here.  See `perldoc -f splice` for details.
- perl's `map` function applies an expression to each element of an array (list).  In this case, the list is the elements returned by the splice function.  The expression used by `map` here returns `0` if an element matches the regex `/^0$/` or a 1 if it doesn't match.  `map` returns an array, which is assigned to array variable `@out`.  See `perldoc -f map` for details.

  BTW, I could have used a string equality comparison (`eq`) with the ternary operator (i.e. `$_ eq "0" ? 0 : 1`) instead of a regex.  A string comparison would be faster than a simple regex like this, but not noticeably so unless your .csv file was huge (many thousands of lines).  Even so, it would be better to use `eq` - the only reason I used `/^0$/` is that it's the first thing that came to mind.

  A numeric comparison (`==`, i.e. `$_ == 0 ? 0 : 1`) wouldn't have worked for your needs because strings that don't start with numbers (ignoring any leading whitespace) will evaluate as 0 and you need them to become 1s.
- `unshift` does the opposite of `shift` - it adds elements to the start of the array.  In this case, it adds what's left of the `@F` array (i.e. the first two elements that weren't removed by the `splice`) to the beginning of the `@out` array.   See `perldoc -f unshift`.
- Finally, the `@out` array is joined by commas and printed.  For details on the `join` function used, see `perldoc -f join`.

---

This can be shortened to just one statement:

```
perl -F, -lne 'print join ",", @F[0..1], map { /^0$/ ? 0 : 1 } splice @F,2' Test.csv
```

There's no need for `@out` as a temp variable, and no need for `unshift` either.

It works exactly the same, but is harder to understand, especially for someone unfamiliar with perl....you have to kind of read it from back to front so you can tell what input each of the functions is getting.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split(",");   \
             @a[2..*] = do for @a[2..*] { $_ ~~ 0.Int ?? 0 !! 1 };  \
             @a.join(",").put ;'   file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split(",");   \
             @a[2..*] .= map: { $_ ~~ 0.Int ?? 0 !! 1 };   \
             @a.join(",").put ;'   file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split(",");   \
             @a[2..*] .= map: { +( $_ !~~ 0.Int ) };   \
             @a.join(",").put;'   file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. It features built-in, high-level support for Concurrency, Asynchrony, and Parallelism (CAP).

Above, the first two code examples bear remarkable similarity to the excellent Perl answers posted by @cas. Of note, Raku has an asymmetric `~~` "smartmatching" operator, which is syntactic sugar for Raku's `.ACCEPTS()` method (*i.e. "Does the RHS accept the LHS?"*). Many "Type"-related issues can be resolved using Raku's `~~` "smartmatching" operator.

Raku also has a new format for the built-in ternary operator: (**Test**) `??` **True** `!!` **False**. Some people find this ternary operator easier to read. Alternatively, the third example uses the fact that `~~` sets the return variable after comparison, allowing the resultant `True`/`False` values to be coerced via `+(…)` or `(…).Int` to `0`/`1` .

*[In the code examples above, the RHS `.Int` is actually superfluous, and smartmatching works quite well without any additional coercions. However you can perform LHS/RHS coercion ( via `.Str`, `.Int`, `.Bool`, etc.) if you have the need for a specific comparison not addressed by any of the defaults].*

Sample Input:

```
Iss1,1,0,0,Hsapiens-I34,0,0,0,Mmusculus-H01,0,0
Iss1,11,0,Scerevisiae-U09,Hsapiens-I05,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,Hsapiens-I05,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I31,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,Mmusculus-H13,0,0,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I31
Iss1,41,0,Scerevisiae-U09,0,0,0,0,0,0,Hsapiens-I21
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,Scerevisiae-U25,0,Hsapiens-I21
Iss1,61,0,0,Hsapiens-I34,0,0,0,Mmusculus-H13,0,0
```

Sample Output:

```
Iss1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Iss1,61,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

Note: the above code will convert blank values, `00`, `0x0`, `-0`, and `0.0` all to `0` zeroes. In particular for blank (empty) values, you should verify that all columns are filled with the code `raku -ne '.split(",", :skip-empty).elems.say;'`, with/without the `:skip-empty` parameter to detect differences. For Perl fans, see the Raku Docs section ['0' is True](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#%270%27_is_True).

---

<sup>Take a look at Perl answers if you want a different treatment for blank values, `00`, `0x0`, `-0`, and `0.0`. The Perl answer by @StéphaneChazelas includes an explanation of how these values (and blanks) are treated. In my hands, the Perl answer by @cas changes blank values, `00`, `0x0`, `-0`, and `0.0` all to `1` (different treatment for blank values than @StéphaneChazelas Perl answer). So you have your choice (two languages, three treatments)!</sup>

---

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://docs.raku.org/routine/ACCEPTS
[https://docs.raku.org/routine/~](https://docs.raku.org/routine/%7E)~
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you could do

```
sed 's/,[[:alpha:]][^,]*/,1/g'
```

This is: Replace any field starting with an alphabetic character by a 1. Including the comma before the field prevents replacing the first field.

The second field is always a number, so it will not get replaced either. If you want to make the script cover cases with the second field starting with a letter, you could "escape" it temporarily:

```
sed 's/,/,-/;s/,[[:alpha:]][^,]*/,1/g;s/,-/,/'
```

This is obviously less elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another `perl` approach, modifying `@F` in place:

```
$ perl -F, -le 'map {$_ &&= 1} @F[2..$#F]; print join ",", @F' test.csv
Iss1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iss1,21,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
Iss1,31,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,41,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Iss1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Iss1,61,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

Elements are changed to `1` if they're considered as *true*, that is if they're neither `0` nor the empty string. Other representations of zero such as `00`, `0x0`, `-0` `0.0` or `zero` are treated as *true* and changed to `1`.